# apt-add-repository: AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'detach'

Tags: apt, python, repository

I am trying to add the following repository.

```
sudo apt-add-repository –y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
```

This returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 22, in <module>
    sys.stdout.detach(), encoding="UTF-8", line_buffering=True)
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'detach'
```

If I change shebang to

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
```

The following error is encountered

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
ImportError: No module named 'softwareproperties'
```

I use `pyenv` for python version management. Tried different versions, but error remains.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: What does `python --version` return?

Comment: Its `Python 2.7.6` .

Comment: What `which python` returns?

Comment: `/usr/bin/python`